# Crystal Report is keep asking for username and password

Tags: ado.net

I have created an crystal report which connects with the ADO.net data set. It is working fine at my system.However when I am trying to use the same report in another machine.It is asking for database log in. Please help to resolve this issue. Feel free to ask if you need any more information regarding this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Show your connection string in web.config

Answer (score 0):

You have probably setup the connection to your database using pass-through authentication (or "Trusted Connection"). When running locally it's connecting as you, but when running on the server it's trying to connect to the database as the user that it's running as (probably a local user account).

Instead, create a new user on your database server and give it access to your DB. Then change your connection string to be something like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

and with a bit of luck you'll be in.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this error by:

1-get the data from database

2-store this data in dataset

3-set the datasource of report to dataset

4-show the report